# Эмуляция нажатий по экрану на андроид устройстве

Tags: android, python, поиск-библиотек

Какая библиотека в пайтон может эмулировать нажатия по экрану на андроид устройстве, и как ее использовать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ит симс ту би импасибл. В смысле "Не реально". Питон вообще не для андроида. Джаву надо. or

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381143/touch-swipe-or-drag-events-emulating-on-android-not-working